# How are I3_min and I3_max currents considered in design for discrete 4-20mA current transmitter?

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, analog, texas-instruments, 4-20ma

How to consider Iout_min and Iout_max currents before fixing up the R1, R2, R3 and R4?
[The document by TI for 4-20mA current loop using discrete components](https://www.ti.com/lit/snoaa73)

For linear operation, the ratio of the current through R3 when Vin = Vin_max and Vin = Vin_min, I3_max / I3_min,
must be equal to the ratio of the maximum output current to the minimum output current, Iout_max / Iout-min.

We need to match this point, Considering resistor values of R1,R2, R3 and R4.
The maximium input voltage is 10V for the design considerations.

Comment: You asked this and it was closed.  Go fix the problem on the closed question.